# Mathjax fallback: Try SVG before image fonts if HTML-CSS webfont fails

Tags: javascript, svg, mathjax, mathml

(I am using STIX fonts, but the question is relevant for TeX fonts as well.)

My question: How do I configure mathjax on my web page so that a user viewing the page experiences the following 1 -> 2 -> 3 fallback chain?

1. HTML-CSS (webFont "STIX-Web", local "STIX")
2. SVG ("STIX-Web")
3. All other fallback options (local generic, image, etc)

In other words, the idea is to keep HTML-CSS as the top choice, but **if HTML-CSS fails, then fall back to SVG, not to local generic or image fonts**.

The fallback needs to work for all kinds of failures of (1). E.g., it should work both when local fonts in HTML-CSS cannot be used (either because the user does not have the fonts locally installed, or because I explicitly disable local fonts in the web page via `availableFonts: []` and `preferredFont: null`), and also when HTML-CSS web fonts cannot be used (the user has disabled webfonts, browser same origin policy gets enforced, etc).

It should also work independent of the client user's last selection of the renderer in the math contextual menu. Currently, if on the client browser the user had last selected HTML-CSS as the renderer via the math menu, then whenever (1) fails, mathjax is falling back to (3), skipping (2). And if the user had last selected SVG as the renderer, then HTML-CSS is no longer the first preferred choice, i.e. (1) is skipped altogether.

Comment: Just to clarify, this was a _server side_ question:  How do I configure mathjax on my web pages so that viewers of my pages see the above fallback behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

> The following config seems to implement the needed fallback chain
>   (in my limited testing).

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="../MathJax-2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG">
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
//
// - Mathjax config to implement the following fallback chain:
//
//     1. HTML-CSS webFont ("STIX-Web")
//     2. SVG ("STIX-Web")
//     3. Other fallback fonts (local generic, image, etc)
//
// - Change availableFonts to ["STIX"] and preferredFont to "STIX"
//   to allow local STIX fonts. Implements the fallback chain below:
//
//     1. HTML-CSS local ("STIX")
//     2. HTML-CSS webFont ("STIX-Web")
//     3. SVG ("STIX-Web")
//     4. Other fallback fonts (local generic, image, etc)
//

//
// Use STIX font consistently across HTML-CSS and SVG
//
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX", "input/MathML",
        "output/HTML-CSS", "output/SVG", "output/PreviewHTML"
    ],
    "HTML-CSS": {
        imageFont: null,
        webFont: "STIX-Web",
        availableFonts: [],    // Or: ["STIX"], to allow local
        preferredFont: null    // Or: "STIX", to allow local
    },
    "SVG": {
        font: "STIX-Web"
    }
});

MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End Jax", function() {

    // 1. Set HTML-CSS as the initially preferred output processor.
    //    (Temporarily overrides the renderer value set by MathMenu
    //    without affecting the user's chosen renderer elsewhere.)
    var jax = "HTML-CSS";
    MathJax.Hub.setRenderer(jax);

    // 2. Install callback which switches renderer to SVG if HTML-CSS fails.
    var nopast = true;
    MathJax.Hub.Startup.signal.Interest(QueSVGfallback, nopast);

});

</script>

<script>
//
// This callback (when installed) scans through messages to check
// (as in FontWarnings.js) if HTML-CSS font loading has failed.
// If so, it queues a request to switch to SVG rendering.
//
var QueSVGfallback = (function() {    // Anonymous "closure" to keep quecount
    var quecount = 0;
    return function(m) {              // The real callback function
        if (quecount > 0) return;     // Prevent multiple queueing
        m = m + "";
        if (m.match(/HTML-CSS Jax - /)) {
            if (m.match(/- using image fonts/) ||
                    m.match(/- no valid font/) ||
                    m.match(/- disable web fonts/)) {
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(
                    ["setRenderer", MathJax.Hub, "SVG", "jax/mml"],
                    ["Rerender", MathJax.Hub]
                );
                quecount++;
            }
        }
    }
})();
</script>
```